# Does the Nexto DS2730 modify files in any way when it imports RAW files?

Tags: canon, raw, file-transfer

I am looking at Nexto DS2730 as a portable backup for photos and videos taken with my Canon EOS 7D on CompactFlash memory cards.

Having googled and learned portable photo storage (PPS) could modify raw files when a PPS copies/imports the files, I'll appreciate any answer with first-hand experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description of the product on the [product page](http://www.nextodi.com/product/en_nd2730.html) it appears to copy the files exactly.  You can see it mentions the "Copy & Verify" feature which checks that they are a bit for bit match.